# `.comm` directive in GAS not showing in `.o` file?

Tags: gnu-assembler

This is a purely pedagogical question.

I have the following C code, in a file called comm.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a;

int main(){
  printf("%d", a);
  return 0;
}
```

The code prints "0\n".

Compiling with gcc -S, I get the following assembly code:

```
        .file   "comm.c"
        .text
        .comm   a,4,4
        .section    .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "%d"
        .text
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        movl    a(%rip), %eax
        movl    %eax, %esi
        leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    printf@PLT
        movl    $0, %eax
        popq    %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 9.1.0"
        .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I am confused as to what .comm a,4,4 is doing. According to 7.96 of
the GNU as manual, the .text directive, it assembles what follows into
the end of the .text section. Thus, I would think that the beginning
of the .text section contains four bytes allocated to storing the
contents of a. This appears to not be the case, because if we
disassemble the .o file, we find:

```
comm.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   8b 05 00 00 00 00       mov    0x0(%rip),%eax        # a <main+0xa>
   a:   89 c6                   mov    %eax,%esi
   c:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi        # 13 <main+0x13>
  13:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  18:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  1d <main+0x1d>
  1d:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  22:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  23:   c3                      retq
```

*Why aren't there four extra bytes at the beginning of =text=*, as is
 promised by the .text GAS directive? Of course, that would be stupid, to put data in the text segment.

So I guess my question is: what is `.comm` doing? Why is it placed under a `.text` directive?

Answer (score 1):

`.comm` does not allocate in the `.text` section, but in the `.bss` section.

From https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas-2.9.1/html_chapter/as_7.html#SEC76 and https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Comm.html#Comm:

> If ld does not see a definition for the symbol--just one or more common symbols--then it will allocate length bytes of uninitialized memory.

It is the linker's job to allocate and map the .comm symbols.
You can see this when you link the program and read the symbols table:

```
gcc comm.o -o comm
readelf comm -s
```

The relevant symbols:

```
Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
 24: 0000000000004030     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   24 
 31: 0000000000004030     1 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   24 completed.7392
 57: 0000000000004038     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 _end
 59: 0000000000004034     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 a
 60: 0000000000004030     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 __bss_start
```

`__bss_start`(`0000000000004030`) is the start of the `.bss` section, and `_end`(`0000000000004038`) is the end of the executable(and in this case also the end of the `.bss` section).

As the 4 bytes of `a` are at addresses `0000000000004034-0000000000004037`, `a` is obviously in the `.bss` section.

And it does show in the `.o`, just not where you were looking for.
You can read the symbols in the `.o` file the same way and something like this will show up:

```
$ readelf comm.o -s

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 13 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS comm.c
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     3: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 
     4: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 
     5: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5 
     6: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    7 
     7: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    8 
     8: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6 
     9: 0000000000000004     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  COM a
    10: 0000000000000000    36 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 main
    11: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
    12: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND printf
```